# Is binomial dispersion the same as binomial distribution?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I have been asked by a client to write a program in R which calculates the "binomial dispersion test." I have not found anything for this, but I have found that you can calculate the [binomial distribution](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Binomial.html).

Are they the same thing? I suspect they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the discussion in this [link](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/aim/2004/04-259/notes/DispersionTests.pdf), it would appear that the binomial *dispersion test* assesses whether the dispersion of the data is substantially divergent from what we would expect of a binomial *distribution.* The binomial distribution and binomial dispersion test are not the same, but are clearly related, since the former assesses a feature of data which may have been drawn from the latter.

The [binomial *distribution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is a [probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) describing the results of a series [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with a specified size and probability of success. The classic example is describing the probability that a dice roll will return 6 if I roll the dice some number of times (say, 10). Knowing $Pr(6)$ allows one to describe the range of outcomes and the probability of each.

Here, dispersion is the concept underlying the term-of-art *variance*. This is important because the binomial distribution specifies a particular variance given the parameters (specifically, $np(1-p)$ for size $n$ and probability of success $p$). A sample with dispersion sufficiently far from its theoretical value under the assumption that it is drawn from a binomial distribution may be evidence that the distributional assumption is not met.

Comment: +1. In addition to correctly noting that they "are not the same", it might be helpful for the OP (or future readers) if you explain what they *are*.

Comment: @gung That's a good point. Elaboration added.

Comment: Thanks, @DJE. You might also note that [dispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) here is essentially a synonym for *variance* & that this issue is important because the binomial distribution necessitates a specific value for the variance as a function of the mean. Thus a value of sample dispersion that is sufficiently far from the theoretically appropriate value indicates that the distributional assumptions made by your inferential tests may not be met & hence their validity is in question.

Comment: That seems like a complete & very informative answer for the OP.